# I need help adjusting this code to load from a .txt file, and to randomly select a line from it

Tags: c#

The purpose of the code is to make it so that it loads from a .txt file, then randomly loads a line to display. I fiddled with it, and I need some more help. Any help would be appreciated. It is commented where it needs adjustments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace EquityPicks
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public List<string> appList = new List<string>(7);

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadList();
        }

        public void loadList() // Adjust to load from a text File
        {
            appList.Clear();
            for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
            {
                string text;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            }

            nextUpTextBox.Text = getMember();
            onDeckTextBox.Text = getMember();
            studentsLeftTextBox.Text = appList.Count.ToString();
        }

        public string getMember() // Adjust for Randomness
        {
            string member = appList[0];
            appList.RemoveAt(0);
            return member;
        }

        void NextButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(appList.Count >= 1)
            {
                nextUpTextBox.Text = onDeckTextBox.Text;
                onDeckTextBox.Text = getMember();
            }
            else if (appList.Count == 0)
            {
                nextUpTextBox.Text = onDeckTextBox.Text;
                onDeckTextBox.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                nextUpTextBox.Text = "";
                onDeckTextBox.Text = "";
            }
            studentsLeftTextBox.Text = appList.Count.ToString();
        }

        void ResetButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it would make a great homework assignment!

Comment: Smell: `for(int i =0; i<10; i++)`. What does *magic number* `10` mean?

Comment: part of previous code I deleted. it created a new string called person, then added a number to the end by increasing values.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
string[] array = File.ReadAllLines("path");
```

And then can use:

```
new Random().Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
```

to select a line from the array.

Edit: to clarify

maxValue should be <= array.Length

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Random().Next(0, array.Length)` ? (inclusive lower bound and exclusive upper bound)

Comment: it should, but my example shows what the documentation shows :), I've assumed that he can set bounds on his own.

Comment: Docs says `new Random.Next(...)` or `new Random().Next(...)` ?

Comment: With `new`, `()` required. So, latter is correct. Fixed my comment. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: oh yeah my bad I've forgotten () after random